# Can not use the XmlInputFormat extends TextInputFormat in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, extends, word-count

I am trying to do a WordCount using Hadoop. I want to use XmlInputFormat.class to split the file base on XML tag. The XmlInputFormat.class is [here](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/ad84344e4055b1e6adff5779339a33fa29e1265d/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.java)

**XmlInputFormat.class is extends from TextInputFormat.class**

```
 Job job = new Job(getConf());
 job.setInputFormatClass(XmlInputFormat.class);
```

It shows the error

> The method setInputFormatClass(Class) in the type Job is not applicable for the arguments (Class)

But it's OK when I use

```
Job job = new Job(getConf());
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
```

Why can't we use the extends one? Or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an issue with your Hadoop version. Did you check that the XMLInputFormat class you are using is actually the right one for your Hadoop version?

Answer (score 0):

I think the hadoop tutorial using mapred library is outdated, and should take a look at:

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount

I could successfully run XMLInputFormat after slight modification of the code above.

---

Please ignore this answer. I think the cause is because I was using deprecated version of map reduce which use mapred.*.

I had the same problem, and it's resolved when I modified one of imports:

From:
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;

To:
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;

Answer (score 0):

May be you are importing the wrong XmlInputFormat.class in your code. the same happened to me with the TextInputFormat.class, to see I was using the wrong import of the class which eclipse automatically pulled out. The correct class to import was:

org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;